# how to deal with alamofire's async?

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to save the data I got from the JSON fire however, because of Alamofire's async nature I dont get the data I need instantly but only when I tap on the tableviewcell again (and the data is wrong too)

I am wondering what I should do here so that when I tap the tableviewcell it will get the data I needed (instead of empty arrays)

Here's my code:

```
class CurrencyExchangeViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let exchange = currencyExchangeModel()
    var past30DaysDateValueToPass = [String]()
    var past30DaysPriceValueToPass = [Double]()
    var valueToPass = ""



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CurrencyExchangeTableViewCell
    valueToPass = Array(self.exchange.currencyToGetExchangesDictionary.keys)[indexPath.row]
    self.getPastData(currency: valueToPass)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "currencyHistorySegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "currencyHistorySegue") {
        var viewController = segue.destination as? CurrencyHistoricalDataViewController
        viewController?.historicalCurrency = valueToPass
        viewController?.past30DaysPrice = self.exchange.currencyPast30DaysPriceArray
        viewController?.past30DaysDate = self.exchange.currencyPast30DaysDatesArray
    }
}

    func getPastData(currency: String){
    Alamofire.request("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?currency=\(currency)").responseJSON{ (responseData) in
        if responseData.result.value != nil {
            let responseJSON = JSON(responseData.result.value)["bpi"].dictionaryObject
            self.exchange.currencyPast30DaysDatesArray = Array(responseJSON!.keys)
            self.exchange.currencyPast30DaysPriceArray = Array(responseJSON!.values) as! [Double]
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Not related but you are strongly discouraged from using two separate arrays for date and value. Create a custom struct and parse the JSON into **one** array of that struct.

Comment: @vadian thank you for your reply. Would you mind elaborating on why is it discouraged to do so ? Memory problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `performSegue` execute after getting data from Alamofire then remove

```
 performSegue(withIdentifier: "currencyHistorySegue", sender: self)
```

this line to from `didselect` and place at `getPastData`.

```
func getPastData(currency: String){
    Alamofire.request("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?currency=\(currency)").responseJSON{ (responseData) in
        if responseData.result.value != nil {
            let responseJSON = JSON(responseData.result.value)["bpi"].dictionaryObject
            self.exchange.currencyPast30DaysDatesArray = Array(responseJSON!.keys)
            self.exchange.currencyPast30DaysPriceArray = Array(responseJSON!.values) as! [Double]
          performSegue(withIdentifier: "currencyHistorySegue", sender: self)
     }
  }
```

This will help.